# Cómo encuentro donde está el error en un KB de Genexus 17?

Tags: genexus

Parece compilar bien, pero al dar clic en "Reorganizar" arroja el siguiente error (estoy siguiendo el pdf "GeneXus17CoreCourse_PracticalExcercises_sp"):

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:FrameworkPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /v:q /m  "C:\KB\Parks\Parks\CSharpModel\build\LastBuild.sln"
> "C:\KB\Parks\Parks\CSharpModel\web\bin\reor.exe" -nogui
> The last reorganization has failed and you are trying to execute a different reorganization
> Unexpected errors may occur if you don't try to finalize previous reorganization before running this one
> If you want to run this reorganization anyway, use '-ignoreresume' parameter in the Reorganization Options property of the generator
> The reorganization process was not successfully completed.
> Failed: Reorganization
> error: Error in reorganization
> Failed: Run Developer Menu

Lo ultimo que agregué fueron las siguientes reglas:

```
error("Debe ingresar el Nombre") 
if EmployeeName.IsEmpty();
error("Debe ingresar el Apellido") 
if EmployeeLastName.IsEmpty();
msg("Está dejando vacío el numero de celular") 
if EmployeePhone.IsEmpty();
default(EMPLOYEEAddedDate, today());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te está dando ocurre cuando pasa lo siguiente:

- Se hicieron cambios en la estructura de la base de datos
- Se mandó a correr la reorganización de la base pero en algún punto ésta falló
- Luego se hicieron más cambios en la estructura de la base de datos (agregar reglas en una trn no modifica la estructura de la base de datos)
- Se impacta y ahi se detecta que ahora hay una nueva reorg pero la anterior no había terminado con éxito

Agregar el argumento  `-ignoreresume` en las *Reorganization Options* del generador evita que se haga el chequeo pero la nueva reorg puede fallar pues la anterior no había terminado con éxito.

Si ésta es una KB de pruebas como parece entonces podrías en vez de impactar la base de datos recrearla (`Build` -> `Create Database Tables`).

Comment: Funcionó bien! pero se perdieron los datos. Menos mal que eran datos de prueba. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar agregando el parámetro **-ignoreresume** a las opciones de reorganización del generador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por esta respuesta, también,.